# How to fix ZeroDivisionError: Division by zero?

Tags: python, error-handling, average, division

After running the code I'm receiving a ZeroDivisionError! Can someone explain what is going on? Looking for an average of bscore and gscore inputs

```
bscore = 0
gscore = 0
bcount = 0
gcount = 0

choice = input("Boy (b), Girl (g) or Quit (q): ")
while (choice != 'q'):
    if(choice == 'b'):
        score = int(input("Boy score: "))
        bscore += score
        bcount == 1
        #z = (x / y) if y != 0 else 0
    elif(choice =='g'):
        score = int(input("Girl score: "))
        gscore += score
        gcount += 1
    else:
            print("Invalid!")
    choice = input("Boy (b), Girl (g) or Quit (q): ")

print("Boy average is: ", (bscore/bcount))
print("Girl average is: ", (gscore/gcount))
```

Comment: Bcount == 1 does nothing

Comment: `bcount == 1` was supposed to be `bcount += 1`. It looks like you didn't hit Shift when you wanted to. (Close-voting as typo.)

Comment: Well, for starters, what do you think would happen if you don't input any score for a boy? What would `bscore/bcount` yield?

Comment: Gotcha so you would have to input a bscore and gscore for results on both!

Comment: @Mr.PlayNoGames That's right. You might as well require the user to enter at least one value for each one of them, **or** consider this edge case when calculating the average, e.g. `print("Boy average is: ", bscore/(bcount or 1))`

Comment: [Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace 
`bcount == 1` with `bcount += 1`. `bcount == 1` is a boolean statement which doesn't do anything here. It seems like you want to increment the count at that point.

Also, even after that, there could be a `ZeroDivisionError` since it could be that the input was never `b` or `g`. I would recommend having an if condition before you try to divide when printing.

Comment: That would be one source of error. OP never increments `bcount` and is initialised at 0. So division by that would most definitely lead to that error, even though would've input  `b` and the corresponding score

Comment: @MatiasCicero - if `bcount` never gets incremented because of the error in this line then it will always stay `0`  and could produce the error wen it is used as a divisor.

Comment: It is working now the  "bcount == 1" was a syntax error on my part!

Comment: You would need to have a check at the time you do the division in case there were no boy or girl entries though before dividing as their counts would stay at 0 @Mr.PlayNoGames